# I cannot update entity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

Category Table ;

```
    public int CategoryId{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public List<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
```

I add new field to the table;

```
    public int CategoryId{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public List<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    public string Url{ get; set; }
```

I get the following error when updating entity;
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'

```
 eShopContext;
            public DbSet<Product> Products{ get; set; }
            public DbSet<Category> Categories{ get; set; }
            public object Configuration { get; internal set; }
    
            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                    @"Server=gdagad;Database=eStoreAppDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            }
    
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
                modelBuilder.Entity<ProductCategory>()
                    .HasKey(c => new {c.CategoryId, c.ProductId});  
            }
        }
```

SeedDatabase.cs;

Comment: Can you show all of the exception message? Did you add the `Url` field to the database?

Comment: I get this error when I try to update-database.
Error Message:SqlException: Invalid column name 'Url'.

Comment: Add a `Url` field to the `Category` table in your database. Field is missing from db.

Answer (score 0):

Use the EF Core Migrations feature to update the database.

```
 1. Add-Migration AddUrl

 2. Update-Database
```

[**add a new field to an ASP.NET Core MVC app**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/new-field?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: If it works, please accept this answer and it may also help others. :P